# mini_magick gem doesn't work with my ImageMagick install

Tags: ruby, macos, minimagick

I have the ImageMagick installed via MacPorts and the mini_magick gem and I get an error for the following script. How can I resolve this problem?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mini_magick'

image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.jpg")
image.resize "100x100"
image.write  "output.jpg"



/Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:164:in `create': MiniMagick::Invalid (MiniMagick::Invalid)
    from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:73:in `read'
    from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:134:in `block in open'
    from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:133:in `open'
    from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:133:in `open'
    from minimagick.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 13):

Try reinstall ImageMagick, if you use Mac OS X:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick jpeg libtiff jasper
brew install imagemagick
```

For check if JPG format is now available:

```
identify -list format | grep JPG
```

This will return the available formats JPG...

Comment: I had to install ImageMagick with `--build-from-source` flag.

Comment: I first only reinstalled imagemagick. No success. I didn't had jasper, but removing jpeg and libtiff as well and then reinstall imagemagick did it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though MiniMagick can't understand the file. See [this comment in the source](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick/blob/97a2f8aef3596dc4086693976faa86b6fdd867a3/lib/mini_magick.rb#L190-196):

> Checks to make sure that MiniMagick can read the file and understand
>   it.
>
> This uses the 'identify' command line utility to check the file. If
>   you are having issues with this, then please work directly with the
>   'identify' command and see if you can figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I have tried it now with a PNG image and it works, but I also need it to work with jpegs and that creates the above error.

Comment: This is the output of the identify command. I have tried it with different valid jpegs.                                               identify: no decode delegate for this image format `input.jpg'.

Comment: I know the Homebrew version of ImageMagick [depends on an external jpeg library](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/ce082c167cba9e5df3c95e429ec510da8a29fa19/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb#L69); is it possible the MacPorts version doesn't install one by default?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it broke after installing ghostscript, through homebrew. I think ghostscript installed some ImageMagick dependency and broke it. Reinstalling ImagEMagick fixed the issue. :)