# Rails 3 + Carrierwave: File Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to set up carrierwave for my Rails project. I've looked at other answers but nothing seems to work. When I try to create an image it gives me this:

```
    1.9.3p392 :003 > bi = BookCoverImage.new
     => #<BookCoverImage id: nil, file: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, book_id: nil, category_id: nil, collection_id: nil, creator_id: nil, group: "BookCoverImage", homepage_slide_id: nil> 
    1.9.3p392 :004 > bi.file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/sample_img.jpg")
     => #<File:/Users/emai/Documents/mysite/spec/support/sample_img.jpg> 
    1.9.3p392 :005 > bi.save
       (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
       (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     => false 
    1.9.3p392 :006 > bi.valid?
     => false 
    1.9.3p392 :007 > bi.errors.full_messages
     => ["File Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid"]
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Mac Mavericks, and homebrew. Can anyone help?

BookCoverImage model:

```
class BookCoverImage < Image
  default_scope { where(group: self.name) }
  belongs_to :book
  mount_uploader :file, BookCoverImageUploader
end
```

It inherits from Image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file

  after_initialize :set_group
  before_save :set_group

  private

    def set_group
      self.group = self.class.name
    end
end
```

My BookCoverImageUploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class BookCoverImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
      "#{Rails.root}/public/test/file_uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    else
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [80, 10000]
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fit => [159, 10000]
  end

  version :main do
    process :resize_to_fit => [238, 10000]
  end



  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: Can you share the model `BookCoverImage` and the Uploader.

Comment: I updated the question with the info you requested

Comment: Kirti I figured it out. I reinstalled using Hugo's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960683/mini-magick-gem-doesnt-work-with-my-imagemagick-install

Answer (score 3):

The error `File Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid` is thrown if `ImageMagick` fails to `identify` the given file as an image.

Try this on the command prompt: (Replace with your filename)

```
> identify spec/support/facebook.jpg 
### If image identified correctly, outputs as below
spec/support/facebook.jpg JPEG 400x267 400x267+0+0 8-bit sRGB 13.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000

> identify spec/support/test.png
### If image is invalid, outputs as below
identify: improper image header `spec/support/test.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4003.
```